# OpenCV or kinect for hand-recognition project?

Tags: opencv, kinect

I am looking for advice on using OpenCV or Kinect on my project. I would welcome your advice. Here are the specifications.

In a 10 X 10 room, a person moves freely and one (or many) camera track the hands (not only one but both).
If the pinky touches the thumb (from any of both hands), I am going to toggle the michophone on for speech-recognition.
When the pinky is released from the thumb, audio acquisition completes and speech-recognition is solicited to complete.

Challenges:

- Distance: a 10 X 10 room is not just in front of a camera.
- Two hands to track, not just one.
- Let's not assume the person is standing on its both feet in front of the camera, the subject may be lying down, sitting or else.

What should I use, OpenCV, or Kinect?

Thank you

Comment: OpenCv is a software library and Kinect is a hardware device so you need them both in your project

Comment: Yes, but OpenCV works with normal images acquired from traditional sources (like a webcam). If I understand well your comment, these traditional sources acquisitions are not enough. Correct?